# Xcode 7 cannot read all keys from Localizable.strings file

Tags: swift, localization

I'm using xcode 7.1.1 and i have got annoying issue while doing localization.
Most of the keys gave me value but some keys return key not a value.

For example

```
"NewVersion"="Versión de Actualización";
"Updates"="Actualizaciones";
"MSG_ConnectionFailed"="Falló la conexión";
```

i can read `"NewVersion"` properly and it returns `"Versión de Actualización"` but while reading `"Updates"` it returns `"Updates"` not its value. it is very weird.

Function which i am using

```
class func GetResource(key : String) -> String
    {
        return NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")
    }
```

Comment: Show the code you're using

Comment: @Wain i updated the question , Please check

Comment: Are you logging the keys to ensure they exactly match, and have you cleaned the build and checked the correct file is installed in the app?

Comment: Yes @Wain , i'm sure about it

Comment: Do you perhaps have a line `"Updates"="Updates";` elsewhere in your resources? I don't know if xcode 7.1.1 checks for duplicate keys, but this type of mistake happens a lot when several developers work together on the same resources.